# CORS Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ReactJS as a frontend and getting error on hitting API.
API is created on Windows Server using ASP.NET MVC.
All APIs are working fine on postman.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.testserver.com/api/GetCity' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

It works only when I disable CORS in browser.

```
brave.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security "http://localhost:3000"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not add an 'Origin' header in your request.

'Origin' and 'Access-Control-Request-Method' are necessary in your request headers.

But I think it is OK to disable CORS in your browser for local test. Since localhost should not appear in the header for production environment.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request